# Present a greedy algorithm to find a longest cycle in an unweighted graph

Tags: algorithm, graph, path-finding, graph-traversal

I could only think of a trivial solution to find all cycles in the graph and then find the number of edges in each cycle and then return the one with maximum edges.

How do I find a longest cycle using a greedy algorithm?

Comment: This problem is NP-hard, so no known efficient greedy algorithms are known for it.

Answer (score 0):

"The longest simple cycle problem is the problem of
finding a cycle of maximum length in a graph. As a
generalization of the Hamiltonian cycle problem, it is NPcomplete on general graphs and, in fact, on every class of graphs
that the Hamiltonian cycle problem is NP-complete. The longest
simple cycle problem may be solved in polynomial time on
the complements of comparability graphs. It may also be solved
in polynomial time on any class of graphs with bounded tree
width or bounded clique-width, such as the distance-hereditary
graphs. However, it is NP-hard even when restricted to split
graphs, circle graphs, or planar graphs. In this paper a heuristic
algorithm is proposed which can solve the problem in polynomial
time. To solve the longest simple cycle problem using adjacency
matrix and adjacency list by making a tree of given problem to
find the longest simple cycle as the deepest path in tree following
reconnect the leaf node of deepest path with root node. The result
resolves the open question for the complexity of the problem on
simple unweighted graphs. The algorithm is implemented on a
simple labeled graph without parallel edges and without selfloop. The worst case time complexity for the proposed algorithm
is O(V+E).

The Longest Simple Cycle Algorithm
In the Proposed Algorithm, the input graph considered to be a
simple graph (i.e. without self-loop and without parallel
edges), the algorithm for Longest Simple Cycle in simple
graph is summarized below:

1. Enumerate all the nodes to calculate degree of each node to
   find the node with highest degree.
2. Assign the node with highest degree as the root for tree.
3. Construct a tree T of the given graph G considering the
   adjacent nodes as successor and predecessors accordingly
   for each vertex using adjacency matrix.
4. Do apply the proposed LSC algorithm to find the longest
   path.
5. Join the leaf node of the longest path with root and retrieve
   the path considering it as the longest cycle in graph."

[A Heuristic Algorithm for Longest Simple Cycle Problem](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/278009819_A_Heuristic_Algorithm_for_Longest_Simple_Cycle_Problem)